# how to define "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "parameters_content" section

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use the azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "my-arm-template" {

  parameters_content = { 
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
  }
  name                = "my_name"
   ...
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "parameters_content": string required.
```

How should I define the parameters_content section?

Comment: @luk2302 could you give an example?

Comment: `parameters_content = jsonencode({location = ...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `jsonencode` the actual argument, like

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "my-arm-template" {

  parameters_content = jsonencode({ 
    location = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
  })
   ...
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to pass an integer parameter to the template. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: This answer has the incorrect schema and fails to deploy. Consider using MorNando's answer instead which worked for us.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue and luk2302 sent me on the right track, but it needed a slight change to his answer. Thanks for your help luk2302!

The correct answer to this is:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "my_template_resource_name" {
  name                = var.my_friendly_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name

  template_content = file("template_name.json")

  parameters_content = jsonencode({ 
     "location" = {
        value = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
     }
     "variable2" = {
        value = var.variable2
      }
  })

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}
```

Comment: could you tell me what is the type of variable2? I am now struggling to pass integer values to my template.

Comment: @fascynacja you will need to declare a parameters block in template_name.json with something like this:         "variable2": {
            "type": "int",
        }

Comment: further reading on template format [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax#parameters)

Comment: I did that, but even I have passed integer parameter, I got an error.

Comment: the error was was comming from something else, in the end i managed to use int params:)

Comment: This solution works perfect for me, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It provides the correct schema for the parameters, unlike the accepted one, which does it incorrectly.